# I want to print listview record from my database

Tags: vb.net, listview, printing

Here is my code for listview with database

```
 Sub fillsview()
    Try
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        'Safe in SQL iNJECT'
        objcmd = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_pcperipherals", objconn)
        'Unsafe Vulnerable in SQL INJECT'
        'strsql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_pcperipherals"'
        'objcmd = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strsql, objconn)'
        objdr = objcmd.ExecuteReader
        While (objdr.Read)
            With ListView1.Items.Add(objdr("ProductID"))
                .SubItems.add(objdr("ProductName"))
                .subitems.add(objdr("ProductBrand"))
                .subitems.add(objdr("ProductCategory"))
                .subitems.add(objdr("ProductQuantity"))
                .subitems.add(objdr("ProductDescription"))
                .subitems.add(objdr("ProductManufacturer"))
                .subitems.add(objdr("Stock"))
                .subitems.add(objdr("Supplier"))
                .subitems.add(objdr("ContactNo"))
            End With
        End While
        objcmd.Dispose()
        objdr.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Me.fillsview()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here are my code for print button

```
   Private Sub btnprint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnprint.Click
    PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
    PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
    With PrintDocument1
        .PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = False
        .Print()
    End With
End Sub
```

and This is my code for printpage

```
    Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim H As Integer = 0
    H = 50
    e.Graphics.DrawString("PRINT", New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 50, H)
    For Each Itm As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.Text, New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 50, H)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.SubItems(0).Text, New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 150, H)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.SubItems(1).Text, New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 150, H)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.SubItems(2).Text, New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 150, H)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.SubItems(3).Text, New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 150, H)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.SubItems(4).Text, New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 150, H)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.SubItems(5).Text, New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 150, H)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.SubItems(6).Text, New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 150, H)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.SubItems(7).Text, New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 150, H)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.SubItems(8).Text, New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 150, H)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.SubItems(9).Text, New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10), Brushes.Black, 150, H)
        H += 20
    Next
End Sub
```

And the Problem when i click and the printpreview show up all text is in the same place i hope you help me out with this one.

[this is the picture please click it to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYBzB.png)

Comment: so i need to change other 150 to not have the same positons?

Comment: Sorry, no, you need to change H at each Drawstring if you want the output to be on different lines

Answer (score 0):

Do this, for example:

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim y = 50
    Dim f as New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 10)

    e.Graphics.DrawString("PRINT", f, Brushes.Black, 50, h)

    y += 10

    For Each Itm As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items

        Dim x = 100

        e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.Text, f, Brushes.Black, x, y)

        For i = 0 to 9
            x += 50
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Itm.SubItems(i).Text, f, Brushes.Black, x, y)
        Next i
        
        y += 20
    Next
End Sub
```